# LINQ to Entities query with join inside method for use in MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, t-sql

In my Person table is a RequestedLocation column which stores location IDs.  The IDs match the LocationId column in the Locations table, the Locations table also has the text location names, in the LocatioName column.

In my view, I need to display the string LocationName in the view which has the Person model passed to it. The view will be displaying a List of people in a telerik grid.  CUrrently it works great, except the RequestedLocation column is all integers.

I am populating all my grids with methods containing LINQ queries.  Here is the method that currently works:

```
    public List<Person> GetPeople()
    {
        var query = from p in _DB.Person.ToList()
                    select p;

        return query.ToList();
    }
```

Here is the regular SQL query that works, and I need to convert into LINQ:

```
SELECT ApplicantID
      ,FirstName
      ,LastName
      ,MiddleName
      ,DateofBirth
      ,Gender
      ,RequestedVolunteerRole
      ,RequestedVolunteerLocation
      ,l.LocationName
  FROM Form.Person p
  JOIN dbo.Location l ON p.RequestedVolunteerLocation = l.LocationID
  Order BY ApplicantID
```

Here is my attempt to convert to LINQ:

```
    public List<NewApplicantViewModel> GetPeople()
    {
        var query = from pl in _DB.Person.ToList()
                    join l in _Elig_DB.Locations.ToList() on pl.RequestedVolunteerLocation equals l.LocationID
                    select new
                    {
                        pl.RequestedVolunteerLocation = l.LocationName

                    };
        return query.ToList();
```

The number of errors I get from this are numerous, but most are along the lines of:

```
Cannot convert from type Annonymous to Type List<NewAPplicantModel>
```

and

```
Invalid annonymous type declarator.
```

Please help, and thank you for reading my post.

Oh, and I have only been programming for a couple months, so if I am going about this all wrong, please let me know.  Only thing I have to stick with is the table structure because it is an existing app that I am updating, and changing the location or person tables would have large consequences.

Comment: You're selecting an anonymous class `select new { foo = bar }`, creating a list of those, and trying to return that list. You have to return a list of `NewApplicantViewModel`s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public List<NewApplicantViewModel> GetPeople()
{
    var query = from pl in _DB.Person
                join l in _Elig_DB.Locations on pl.RequestedVolunteerLocation 
                equals l.LocationID
                select new NewApplicantViewModel
                {
                    LocationName = l.LocationName,
                    otherPropery = p.Property
                };
    return query.ToList();
 }
```

Beware of calling _DB.Person.ToList() it will load all persons from DB because ToList() immediately executes the query and the join would be performed in memory (not in DB).

Answer (score 2):

The reason you are getting an error is you are projecting an anonymous type

```
 select new
                {
                    pl.RequestedVolunteerLocation = l.LocationName

                };
```

Instead, you need to project a NewApplicantViewModel

```
 select new NewApplicantViewModel
                {
                    RequestedVolunteerLocation = l.LocationName

                };
```